# How to use dependency instead of loadExterns in flexmojos Maven plugin?

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, flexmojos

The documentation for flexmojos plugin states that loadExterns parameter is deprecated, and suggests: " Use dependency with type "xml" and classifier "link-report" (http://sites.sonatype.org/flexmojos/flexmojos-maven-plugin/compile-swf-mojo.html#loadExterns) . Can somebody please explain or show an example of how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [wiki page](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Adding+libraries+to+compilation) that explain's flexmojos' use of the maven dependency mechanism to generate mxmlc and compc configurations.

I didn't find the `link-report` classifier in it, but the mechanism should be the same.